# Not sure what's wrong with my LATEX workshop settings

Tags: pdftex, vscode, latex-workshop

I've been using LATEX on VS code now. The .pdf and compile correctly, but everytime I use it, it has this error message.

[image: VS Code Error Message]

LATEX: macTex distribution and LATEXMK installed
VS Code LATEX Workshop installed.

My Settings.json file

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark - C++",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Anonymous Pro",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "latex-workshop.check.duplicatedLabels.enabled": false

    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
    ],
    // LaTeX RECIPES
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "pdflatex ➞ biber ➞ pdflatex × 2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "biber",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
    ],
}
```

My error message from the compiler log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/nasa_william_lu/USYD_VS/LATEX2_Harvard/Harvard.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amscd.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/euscript.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/commath/commath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ccicons/ccicons.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file Harvard.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 88--91


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 88--91

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 125--129


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 160--163

[2]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 217--217


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 217--217


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 217--217


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 220--221

[3]
Overfull \hbox (2.21632pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 247--249
\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Taking the \OT1/cmtt/m/n/12 Riemann sum\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 , slic-ing the in-ter-val into $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 n$ \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 subin-ter-vals $[\OML/cmm/m/it/12 x[]; x[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 )\OML/cmm/m/it/12 ; \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 [\OML/cmm/m/it/12 x[]; x[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 )\OML/cmm/m/it/12 ; [] ; \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 [\OML/cmm/m/it/12 x[]; x[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 ]$
[4]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 306--310


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 306--310

[5]
/Users/nasa_william_lu/USYD_VS/LATEX2_Harvard/Harvard.tex:345: Missing \right. inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \right .
l.345     $
           $
[6] (./Harvard.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `Harvard.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-ts1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi6.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on Harvard.pdf (6 pages, 218841 bytes).
SyncTeX written on Harvard.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Harvard.log.
```

Thank you so much for your support. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error with a minimal document? For example `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello\end{document}`.

Comment: you show the error missing \right so you have an unmatched  \left. you should also fix all those underfill box warnings which are almost certainly misplaced `\\ `

Comment: this is unrelated to vscode you should show your tex file at line 345

Comment: @enkorvaks Yes it has this problem too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have fixed it as follows, but it still have the recipe termination error.

    $$
    Assuming that $<A,C>$ and $<B,D>$ are "equivalent" respectively $$
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
        A=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}a= \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}a  \\
        C=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}c= \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}c\\
        B=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}b= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2b}\\
        D=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}d= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2d}
    \end{aligned}\right.
    $$